# nodejs - exporting "variable" var

Tags: node.js

I have two files in a node.js project; timer.js and app.js.

Basically what timer does is, it has a variable `myNumber` which increases with a `setInterval` function. I would like to be able to access that variable whenever I need it, currently I am using the following code:

```
var myNumber = 0;

setInterval(myMethod, 1);

function myMethod() {
    myNumber++;
    module.exports = myNumber;
}
```

and I got the feeling this is very wrong (I am a complete newbie), can anyone enlighten me on how to do it the right way?

What I'd like to do is that every time I am getting a variable like this in another file, I get the current value of myNumber. Currently I am doing it this way, and it's working (still, this *must* be wrong):

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var timer = require("../timer.js");
    res.end("timer tick at: " + timer);
};
```

Comment: Why not attach `myNumber` to exports: `module.exports.myNumber = myNumber`. Then you can update it directly: `module.exports.myNumber++`. I'm not 100% sure on the intent of the code though...

Comment: so there is no problem in having the `module.exports` inside the loop?

Comment: the intent is to have a forever loop, and access that value when I need it

Comment: be aware that setInterval() has a tendency to drift apart from real clock intervals when running. If you need the time correctly I would use a time difference method by using a timestamp at start and the timestamp on access. Else you are going to end up wirh totally the wrong time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I would just attach `myNumber` to `module.exports`:

```
module.exports.myNumber = 0;

setInterval(myMethod, 1);

function myMethod() {
    module.exports.myNumber++;
}
```

You can update your exported object as much as you want because other modules that `require` your module will share the same reference as `module.exports` in your module code.